# Reading a JSON file with java

Tags: java, json, file

I'm having a problem in reading the "Email" field from a JSON file, using Java. When I try to read it, it only reads the first one, even if I put more than one, I tried different things but nothing seems to go. Any way to solve it?
Here is the code:

This is the sign in method, where I write every data about the customer on the JSON file

```java
JSONObject customer = new JSONObject();
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();   
customer.put("Email", emailCliente.getText());
customer.put("Tipo", "Cliente");
customer.put("Name", nomeCliente.getText());
customer.put("Surname", cognomeCliente.getText());
customer.put("BirthDate", dataNascitaCliente.getText());
customer.put("Address", indirizzoCliente.getText());
customer.put("Phone", telefonoCliente.getText());
customer.put("Password", pswCliente.getText());

list.add(customer);

try {
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("Db.json", true);
    ObjectOutputStream fileWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
    fileWriter.writeObject(list);
    fileWriter.flush();
    fileWriter.close(); 
}
```

This is the code for reading from JSON file:

```
public class Read implements Serializable{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try{
        FileInputStream reader = new FileInputStream("Db.json");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(reader);
        Object customer = (Object) ois.readObject();
        JSONArray tmp = (JSONArray) (customer);
        for(Object obj : tmp) {
            JSONObject tmpObj = (JSONObject) obj;
            System.out.println(tmpObj.get("Email"));
        }
        ois.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} }
```

Comment: "even if I put more than one"  <<  please add the code doing that .

Comment: Maybe *email* should be a ```JSONArray``` instead of a single field

Comment: share the json document that you arr trying to read.

Comment: Search '"reading and writing json". You are not writing in the .json format, which is a text variant, allowing ease of development.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial Use this class is more usefull that org.json objects.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `org.json` library to create and read JSON data.

Don't. That library is deplorably bad.

I know `json.org` lists it.

An excellent choice is [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), or perhaps [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) if you want an alternative. As @Raúl Garcia mentioned in a comment, [here is a good baeldung tutorial on jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial).

NB: `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` are for java's serialization mechanism, which isn't JSON and you don't want those in any case, so, throw out your 'read' code and start from scratch, by following the tutorial. Also, your exception code is problematic; exceptions contain 4 bits of info (type, message, trace, and cause); you're throwing out 3 of the 4 useful bits of info then blindly continuing, which likely produces more clutter in your logs, making it extremely difficult to try to figure out what is going wrong. Stop doing this; just 'throws' such exceptions onwards. If you really, really can't, fix your IDE to generate `catch (Foo e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}` as a default catch block. **NEVER** `e.printStackTrace();`.

Answer (score 0):

You could read it a single line like so when you use unify-jdocs:

```java
Document d = new JDocument(s); // where s is a JSON string
String s = d.getString("$.Email");
```

unify-jdocs is a library I have created to work with JSON documents. It provides a whole lot of other features as well. Check it out on https://github.com/americanexpress/unify-jdocs